# Letsencrypt Certificado SSL no se actualiza

Tags: docker, certificado-ssl, letsencrypt

Me caduco el certificado y no se actualiza :(, al forzar la renovación me dice:

```
[Fri Sep 29 13:12:28 UTC 2023] Create new order error. Le_OrderFinalize not found. {
  "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited",
  "detail": "Error creating new order :: too many certificates (5) already issued for this exact set of domains in the last 168 hours: my.domain.com, retry after 2023-09-29T23:43:21Z: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/duplicate-certificate-limit/",
  "status": 429
}
[Fri Sep 29 13:12:28 UTC 2023] Please check log file for more details: /dev/null
```

Ya elimine los certificados y toda la data que se guarda de Letsencrypt, pero aun asi, no me proporciona el certificado :(

**Que puedo hacer?**

Comment: el mensaje lo dice debes esperar 168 horas, cuando las solicitudes son muy seguidas el sistema de let's hace un bloqueo por un tiempo, te recomiendo verificar tu dominio antes de hacer la peticion del certificado

Comment: Asi fue @John, espere y luego ya solo se soluciono